# Changing Logo for all apps

Tags: app, setup

I am trying to change logo in  my developer account for all apps at once instead of for a single app.

If we change logo can that be applied to all apps in the salesforce org ?

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user3388029 (you can change this to your own name btw!) - There were some close votes on your question so i've taken the liberty of clearing it up the way I interpreted it.

Comment: Changing the logo for all apps at once cannot be done via the standard UI. Why do you want to do this?